# PostgresSQL cannot read data written shortly before

Tags: database, postgresql, libpq

We have a bug where data is written to a Postgres database, using a stored procedure. The commit result indicates success. Approximately 500-700 milliseconds later we try to read the recently-written data (using a stored procedure again). However, the data does not exist in the database.

We use two database sessions- one for read and one for write.

We are using libpq C++ library.

The writes are performed asynchronously in a separate thread. We use a PostGres "pipeline" for writes.

The reads are performed synchronously in the application thread.

We are currently restricted to this architecture due to the way the generic database code was written (unless this is the only way to fix the problem).

Could someone please suggest what might be happening/how to fix?

We changed from stored procedure to "inline" and it made no difference.

Comment: Without the code there is really no way to come up with an answer.

Comment: Are the rows visible later on, or never to be seen?

Comment: @Lennart the rows are visible later on. It's like the data is sat in some intermediary cache.